# Pivoting Data using T-SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

What I want to do is quite simple but I'm struggling. I'm hoping that someone can help.

I have this query that I've written.

```
DECLARE     @LeadGenerator AS nvarchar(20) = 'Employee Name'

SELECT      C.BaseDate AS BaseDate
        ,COUNT(P.OwnCreatedDate) AS CreatedLeads
        ,COUNT(P2.OwnCreatedDate) AS CreatedResearchedLeads
        ,COUNT(P3.AppointmentFeatureDate) AS AppointmentsMade

FROM        dwCalendar C
        LEFT JOIN dwTable P ON P.OwnCreatedDate = C.BaseDate AND P.OwnerStatus NOT IN ('Researched') AND P.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator
        LEFT JOIN dwTable P2 ON P2.OwnCreatedDate = C.BaseDate AND P2.OwnerStatus IN ('Researched') AND P2.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator
        LEFT JOIN dwTable P3 ON P3.AppointmentFeatureDate = C.BaseDate AND P3.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator
WHERE       C.BaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY    C.BaseDate
```

It returns the data in this format:

```
Basedate    | CreatedLeads | CreatedLeads | AppointmentsMade
2015-06-18  | 1            | 2            | 0  
2015-06-19  | 2            | 1            | 2
2015-06-20  | 1            | 1            | 1
2015-06-21  | 1            | 2            | 3
2015-06-22  | 2            | 0            | 0
2015-06-23  | 3            | 2            | 2
2015-06-24  | 0            | 0            | 1
```

I want to pivot the data so that the Dates are across the top and then, CreatedLeads, CreatedLeadsResearched and a AppointmentsMade become the start of the rows and then the data.

So the data looks more like this:

```
                          2015-06-18 | 2015-06-19 | 2015-06-20 | 2015-06-21
CreatedLeads           | Respective data in here
CreatedLeadsResearched |
AppointmentsMade       |
```

If someone could please help that would be great as I am stuck?

Thanks in advance,

Thanks for the help, I've tried the script and this is the sql:

```
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sqlquery VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE     @LeadGenerator AS nvarchar(20) = 'Employee Name'

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct  ',' + QuoteName([BaseDate])
                    FROM dwCalendar FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '') 


SET @sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM
  (

SELECT      C.BaseDate AS BaseDate
        ,COUNT(P.OwnCreatedDate) AS CreatedLeads
        ,COUNT(P2.OwnCreatedDate) AS CreatedResearchedLeads
        ,COUNT(P3.AppointmentFeatureDate) AS AppointmentsMade


FROM        dwCalendar C
        LEFT JOIN dwOwnerTouchPoints P ON P.OwnCreatedDate = C.BaseDate AND P.OwnerStatus NOT IN (''Researched'') AND P.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator
        LEFT JOIN dwTable P2 ON P2.OwnCreatedDate = C.BaseDate AND P2.OwnerStatus IN (''Researched'') AND P2.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator
        LEFT JOIN dwTable P3 ON P3.AppointmentFeatureDate = C.BaseDate AND P3.LeadAssignee = @LeadGenerator

WHERE       C.BaseDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DD, -8, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DD, -1, GETDATE())

GROUP BY    C.BaseDate ) base
   PIVOT (Sum(CreatedLeads) FOR [BaseDate]
   IN (' + @cols + ')) AS finalpivot'

EXECUTE ( @sqlquery )
```

However when I try this I'm getting this error:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11
Must declare the scalar variable "@LeadGenerator".
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'Apr 28 20)) AS 
finalpivot'.
```

Really sorry I just don't understand whats going on here.

Comment: I'm voting to close; it looks like the question that Bernd linked to can give you an answer.  I'm also upvoting your question; it's well written, provides the data to get you an answer, and is all around good; welcome to StackOverflow, that's a great start!

Comment: Thanks both, I've added some more to my question as I'm having problems with the pivot query.